# OnTriggerEnter() and OnCollisionEnter() not working with character controller

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a capsule object with Camera on it. Capsule has capsule collider with mesh, character controller. cylinder object (coin) is box collider with is trigger option being on. OnTriggerObject method doesn't help to destoy the coin object. Even used OnCollisionEnter, eventually have the same result. Also tried with rigidbody added to the player object and removed from coin object. Even don't remember what I tried on.
[image]
[image]
Here is script attached to capsule object:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    [SerializeField] Transform playerCamera = null;
    [SerializeField] float mouseSensitivity = 3.5f;
    [SerializeField] float walkSpeed = 6.0f;
    [SerializeField] float gravity = -13.0f;
    [SerializeField] [Range(0.0f, 0.5f)] float moveSmoothTime = 0.3f;
    [SerializeField] [Range(0.0f, 0.5f)] float mouseSmoothTime = 0.03f;

    [SerializeField] bool lockCursor = true;

    float cameraPitch = 0.0f;
    float velocityY = 0.0f;
    CharacterController controller = null;

    Vector2 currentDir = Vector2.zero;
    Vector2 currentDirVelocity = Vector2.zero;

    Vector2 currentMouseDelta = Vector2.zero;
    Vector2 currentMouseDeltaVelocity = Vector2.zero;
    void Start()
    {
        controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
        if (lockCursor)
        {
            Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
            Cursor.visible = false;
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        UpdateMouseLook();
        UpdateMovement();
    }
    void UpdateMouseLook()
    {
        Vector2 targetMouseDelta = new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Mouse X"), Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y"));

        currentMouseDelta = Vector2.SmoothDamp(currentMouseDelta, targetMouseDelta, ref currentMouseDeltaVelocity, mouseSmoothTime);

        cameraPitch -= currentMouseDelta.y * mouseSensitivity;
        cameraPitch = Mathf.Clamp(cameraPitch, -90.0f, 90.0f);

        playerCamera.localEulerAngles = Vector3.right * cameraPitch;
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * currentMouseDelta.x * mouseSensitivity);
    }

    void UpdateMovement()
    {
        Vector2 targetDir = new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"));
        targetDir.Normalize();

        currentDir = Vector2.SmoothDamp(currentDir, targetDir, ref currentDirVelocity, moveSmoothTime);

        if (controller.isGrounded)
            velocityY = 0.0f;

        velocityY += gravity * Time.deltaTime;

        Vector3 velocity = (transform.forward * currentDir.y + transform.right * currentDir.x) * walkSpeed + Vector3.up * velocityY;

        controller.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime);

    }
    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other)
    {
        if(other.gameObject.tag == "coins")
        {
            Destroy(other.gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: void OnControllerColliderHit(ControllerColliderHit other) doesn't work too (

Comment: Is its tag set to coins? You should be using on trigger enter for this. Also try using on trigger stay.

Comment: @ken, yes the coins have tag "coins", and ontrigger is set

Comment: I meant you should be using OnTriggerEnter instead of OnCollisionEnter. Out a print statement in OnTriggerEnter to see if it is being called at all.

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`unityscript`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a JavaScript flavor like custom language used in early Unity versions and is long **deprecated** by now! You code is clearly `c#`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Collision to work needs at least one rigidbody component, so attach rigidbody, check layers (Project Settings -> Physics)

Also read this:
[collisions unity](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CollidersOverview.html)

> With normal, non-trigger collisions, there is an additional detail that at least one of the objects involved must have a non-kinematic Rigidbody (ie, Is Kinematic must be switched off). If both objects are kinematic Rigidbodies then OnCollisionEnter, etc, will not be called. With trigger collisions, this restriction doesn’t apply and so both kinematic and non-kinematic Rigidbodies will prompt a call to OnTriggerEnter when they enter a trigger collider.

Comment: the Capsule object has rigidbody with is kinematic. the same

Comment: if is kinematic is switched, the same

Comment: Yes, put a Rigidbody on the coin, with kinematic. Don’t have a Rigidbody on the player, though. (I assume you are using character controller)

Comment: I removed rigidbody from the coin and leave it only for the player, didn't help

Comment: @y47999 did you check layers?

Comment: You need to use OnTriggerEnter, not the OnCollisionEnter

Comment: @ken, I am using character controller with rigidbody, the coin doesn't have rigidbody, to be clear

Comment: Use OnTriggerEnter, did that fix it?

Comment: Just try to log every collision Debug.Log("Collision with: "+collision.name"); and verify what is wrong

Comment: Since you are colliding with a *trigger*, you use OnTriggerEnter

Comment: @Wolfik, it has default layer

Comment: @y47999 Did you use OnTriggerEnter(Collider col) yet?

Comment: @ken, void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) and the player has rigidbody

Comment: @y47999 OK good, I was just checking, but then I saw you accepted the answer, so I thought you must have done it.